# Include the count of a queried column in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have the count of col2 in tbl1 attached to the result of this query, how can I do that?

```
create table tbl1 (col1 varchar(20), col2 varchar(20))
create table tbl2 (colA varchar(20), colB varchar(20))

insert into tbl1 (col1,col2) values('foo1','bar1'), ('foo2','bar2'), ('foo3','bar2'),('foo4','bar4'),('foo5','bar1'),('foo6','bar3'), ('foo7','bar3'), ('foo8','bar1'),('foo9','bar6');
insert into tbl2 (colA,colB) values('foo1','bar3'), ('foo2','bar2'), ('foo5','bar1'),('foo6','bar1'),('foo4','bar7'),('foo6','bar1');


SELECT colA,col2 FROM tbl2 LEFT JOIN tbl1 ON colA=col1
```

the desired output should be the same table with a 3rd column that shows the count of col2 in tbl1

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding create/ insert statements.. was great to recreate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery with window functions:

```
SELECT t2.colA, t1.col2, t1.t2_cnt
FROM tbl2 t2 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col2) as t2_cnt
      FROM tbl1 t1
     ) t1
     ON t2.colA = t1.col1;
```

Comment: t1 is a very large table, I am very concerned about the performance since this is a part of many queries, is this the best way?

Comment: @ibo . . . It is hard to think of a faster way to do this, given what the query does.  SQL Server should be able to use indexes on `tbl1(col1)` and `tbl1(col2)` for this query.

Comment: How about making a view and indexing it instead of using the subquery?

Comment: @Ibo . . . There is a lot of overhead to creating such a view.  But if `tbl1` doesn't change then that is definitely a feasible solution.  However, I don't think indexed views support window functions.

Comment: tbl1 rows will be deleted and inserted every week at least if not often, I guess I will just keep it as a table then